# How can i change the text color of every items in prestashop 1.7.6.0?

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I tried to change the text colors of every items in prestashop 1.7.6.0 ,for example , the description of the product. Where can i change the css or insert style type?

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop 1.7.x comes with webpack to compile both js and scss files.
The scss files or normally in your theme folder : /themes/your_theme/_dev/scss

you will find all the documentation here : 
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/compile-assets/

Comment: Did it helped ?